# Python module not found after build/install

Tags: python, python-3.6, setuptools, python-module

I have an internal tool that we are using at work to pull some data and generate a report. The tool was written in python. I made some changes to the tool, and decided to tidy up the folder structure which seemed a bit messy to me. I probably broke something, but I'm determined to fix it and figure out what the issue is.

The project is named ReportCardLite, and my folder structure is like this:

```
ReportCardLite root folder
-Folder 1
-Folder 2
-rclite
-----__init.py__
-----A.py
-----B.py
-----C.py
-setup.py
-setup.cfg
-__init__.py
```

Originally, the author was importing by using the package name, which was odd to me since all the script files were in the same directory. So, in A.py for example, he would say something like "from rclite.B import fun".

I decided to remove the "unnecessary" module name from before all the import statements. Of course, that broke it, but I quickly figured out that I could add a line in my settings.json file to look within the rclite folder for all modules. Now my scripts were importing from one another without the module name, and running fine from within the IDE terminal window.

I next needed to build an executable from this module. The original author had included a setup.py and a setup.cfg file, so I used that to build and install this. But when I run this new executable, I receive errors that modules cannot be found. If I change it back to how it originally was, namely the "rclite.A" qualifier, it runs fine. I've spent hours trying to understand what is going on here, and I'm just out of ideas and cannot find any relevant questions using Google.

Can someone kindly point out which configuration I need to change in order to not have to put "rclite" in front of the import statements? Thanks!

Here is the setup.py script.. didn't see anything that looked promising.

```
"""ReportCardLite Packaging

See:
https://code.amazon.com/packages/ReportCardLite/trees/mainline
"""

# Always prefer setuptools over distutils
from codecs import open
from os import path

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

import sys
# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(name='ReportCardLite',

      # Versions should comply with PEP440.  For a discussion on single-sourcing
      # the version across setup.py and the project code, see
      # https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/single_source_version.html
      version='0.9.0',

      description='RC.Lite for SIM',
      long_description=long_description,

      # See https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
      classifiers=[
          # How mature is this project? Common values are
          #   3 - Alpha
          #   4 - Beta
          #   5 - Production/Stable
          'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',

          # Indicate who your project is intended for
          # 'Intended Audience :: Developers',
          # 'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',

          # Pick your license as you wish (should match "license" above)
          # 'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',

          # Specify the Python versions you support here. In particular, ensure
          # that you indicate whether you support Python 2, Python 3 or both.
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6'
      ],



      # You can just specify the packages manually here if your project is
      # simple. Or you can use find_packages().
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
      #packages = ['rclite'],

      # Alternatively, if you want to distribute just a my_module.py, uncomment
      # this:
      #   py_modules=["my_module"],

      # List run-time dependencies here.  These will be installed by pip when
      # your project is installed. For an analysis of "install_requires" vs pip's
      # requirements files see:
      # https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/requirements.html
      install_requires=[
          'isoweek',
          'jinja2',
          'jsonpickle',
          'jsonplus',
          'markdown',
          'pkg-resources',
          'premailer',
          'python-dateutil',
          'pyxdg',
          'six'
      ],


      options={
          'build_exe': {
              'packages': ['lxml', 'asyncio', 'markdown.extensions'],
              'include_files': ['templates/', 'webapp/']
          },
      },
     # executables = [Executable("rclite/aiohttp_app.py", base="Win32GUI")],
      executables=[Executable(script="rclite/aiohttp_app.py", targetName="run_rclite.exe")],

      # List additional groups of dependencies here (e.g. development
      # dependencies). You can install these using the following syntax,
      # for example:
      # $ pip install -e .[dev,test]
      extras_require={
          'dev': ['wheel'],
          'test': ['mock'],
      },

      # If there are data files included in your packages that need to be
      # installed, specify them here.  If using Python 2.6 or less, then these
      # have to be included in MANIFEST.in as well.
      package_data={
          # 'sample': ['package_data.dat'],
      },

      # Although 'package_data' is the preferred approach, in some case you may
      # need to place data files outside of your packages. See:
      # http://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files # noqa
      # In this case, 'data_file' will be installed into '<sys.prefix>/my_data'
      # data_files=[('my_data', ['data/data_file'])],

      # To provide executable scripts, use entry points in preference to the
      # "scripts" keyword. Entry points provide cross-platform support and allow
      # pip to create the appropriate form of executable for the target platform.
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'rclite = rclite.__main__:main',
              'rclite-gui = rclite.aiohttp_app.__main__'
          ],
      },
      )
```

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out why my setup script builds/installs fine on Linux but on Windows the package lists as installed but the module is missing. Did you figure this out?